# tabs within tabs in HTML/CSS and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs, nested

I want to create a tabbed view in HTML. My problem is that one of the tab have tabs within it. My problem is I don't know how to ensure that the sub-tabs do not show unless I am in profile tab. What is the best way to accomplish this? How can I use javascript to update class accordingly and not show the tabs? Any help would be grateful. My code is

```
            <div class="tabheader">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#addprop_tab" title="">Add Property</a></li>
                <li><a href="#savedprop_tab" title="">Saved Property</a></li>
                <li><a href="#inbox_tab" title="">Inbox</a></li>
                <li><a href="#profile_tab" title="">Update Profile</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div> <!-- End of tabheader -->
        <div class="tabcontent">
            <div id="addprop_tab">
                <p><a href="#" title="Click to add property">Add your property to NPLH</a></p>
                show added property
            </div> <!-- End of addprop_tab -->
            <div id="savedprop_tab">
                <p>Browse your saved properties</p>
            </div> <!-- End of savedprop_tab -->
            <div id="inbox_tab">
                <p>inbox</p>
            </div> <!-- End of inbox_tab -->
            <div id="profile_tab">
                <ul>
                    <a href="#tab1" title="">Tab1</a>
                    <a href="#tab2" title="">Tab2</a>
                    <a href="#tab3" title="">Tab3</a>
                </ul>
            </div> <!-- End of profile_tab -->
        </div> <!-- End of tabcontent -->
        <div class="subtab_content">
            <div id="tab1">
                <p>tab1</p>
            </div> <!-- End of tab1 -->     
            <div id="tab2">
                <p>tab2</p>
            </div> <!-- End of tab2 --> 
            <div id="tab3">
                <p>tab3</p>
            </div> <!-- End of tab3 --> 
        </div>
```

and CSS code is

```
.tabheader {
    width: 1000px;
    position: relative;
    top: -100px;
}

.tabheader ul { 
    list-style-type: none;
}

.tabheader ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 175px;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
    margin: 0px 11px 5px 11px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.tabcontent {
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    top: -100px;
    height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #eee;
}

.tabcontent div {
    height: 40px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.subtab_content {
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    top: -100px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #eee;
}



.subtab_content div {
    height: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Are you using jquery? How you control your tab to show and hide?

Comment: It is taken care of within the CSS by the overflow: hidden line. However, the problem is that if you click on profile_tab - tab1 and then click on other links the tab1 still shows. I think the solution is to create a javascript to update style of subtabs on clicking the links but I do not know how to do that

Comment: You have found your own answer. Start playing with jQuery, it's really easy to learn, and very useful in situations like these.

Comment: I have been looking around ... I would have to loop through children of subtab_content div and change display to block as required. But how do I ensure that for links which have no subtabs the heights etc are appropriate? Should I keep a empty div in subtabs? I have no knowledge of jquery or javascript. Can someone please help me with the code? Thanks

Comment: +1 for tabs without javascript/jQuery :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok forget the previous answer. jQuery tabs or similar solution is the way to go. I was really new to web development when I asked the question

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question here ... this is few hours of work but I do not really know any other variables in javascript. Is this the best way to do this.

Your comments will be highly appreciated.

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function activateTab(mainid, li_id, divid, tabid) {
        var mainDiv = document.getElementById(mainid);
        var li = document.getElementById(li_id);
        var tabDiv = document.getElementById(divid);
        var mainTab = document.getElementById(tabid);

        for (var i = 0; i < mainDiv.childNodes.length; i++) {
            var node = mainDiv.childNodes[i];
            if (node.nodeType == 1) {
                node.style.background = (node == li) ? '#aaa' : 'white';
            }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < tabDiv.childNodes.length; i++) {
            var node = tabDiv.childNodes[i];
            if (node.nodeType == 1) {
                node.style.display = (node == mainTab) ? 'block' : 'none';
            }
        }
    }
```

HTML

```
    <div id="tabheader">
        <ul id="tablist">
            <li id="addprop" style="background: #aaa"><a href="javascript:activateTab('tablist','addprop','tabcontent','addprop_tab')" title="">Add Property</a></li>
            <li id="savedprop"><a href="javascript:activateTab('tablist','savedprop','tabcontent','savedprop_tab')" title="">Saved Property</a></li>
            <li id="inbox"><a href="javascript:activateTab('tablist','inbox','tabcontent','inbox_tab')" title="">Inbox</a></li>
            <li id="profile"><a href="javascript:activateTab('tablist','profile','tabcontent','profile_tab')" title="">Update Profile</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div> <!-- End of tabheader -->
    <div id="tabcontent" class="maintab">
        <div id="addprop_tab" style="display: block">
            <p><a href="#" title="Click to add property">Add your property to NPLH</a></p>
        </div> <!-- End of addprop_tab -->
        <div id="savedprop_tab" style="display: none">
            <p>Browse your saved properties</p>
        </div> <!-- End of savedprop_tab -->
        <div id="inbox_tab" style="display: none">
            <p>inbox</p>
        </div> <!-- End of inbox_tab -->
        <div id="profile_tab" style="display: none">
            <p>
                <ul>
                    <a href="javascript:activateTab('tablist','profile','profile_subtab','tab1')" title="">Tab1</a>
                    <a href="javascript:activateTab('tablist','profile','profile_subtab','tab2')" title="">Tab2</a>
                    <a href="javascript:activateTab('tablist','profile','profile_subtab','tab3')" title="">Tab3</a>
                </ul>
            </p>
            <div id="profile_subtab" class="subtab">
                <div id="tab1" style="display: block">
                    <p>tab1</p>
                </div> <!-- End of tab1 -->
                <div id="tab2" style="display: none">
                    <p>tab2</p>
                </div> <!-- End of tab2 -->
                <div id="tab3" style="display: none">
                    <p>tab3</p>
                </div> <!-- End of tab3 -->
            </div>
        </div> <!-- End of profile_tab -->
    </div> <!-- End of tabcontent -->
```